# Python best practice - should I initialize variables with values?

Tags: python, python-3.x, variables, initialization

I haven't found precise answer to the question (Python).

Is a good practice to intialize variables at the beggining or should that be done later? And what type of the value should I give them at the beginning?

example:

```
variable_str = None  #  Should I give None to them all?
variable_int = None  #  
variable_float = 0.0 # Should I give float for type float?

# Code.......
# I will use that variables later on,....
```

Some say it is a good practice, but I am confused which data type should be used? Python is dynamically typed, but nevertheless what is the best practice?

Comment: No, don't do that.

Comment: Python is dynamically typed so there is no need to declare them with a default value. Just define them when you need them with the appropriate value. You can look at type hints if you want some form of static type checking (e.g. `mypy`), but this is not enforced by CPython at runtime.

Comment: I would discourage it.

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to mention variables before you first need to give them an actual useful value.  Don't put dummy values at the top of your program.